# Regex for list of emails, validating invalid email addresses

Tags: regex, validation

I have the following regex for validation a list of Email addresses seperated by a ';'

```
\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*
```

It used to work correctly (for my tests) until I discovered a problem with it.

It not only allows stuff like this (intended)
Email@domain.com;Email@domain.com;Email@domain.com

It allows stuff like this: (not intended)
Email@domain.comEmail@domain.comEmail@domain.com

Where is the problem with it?

Comment: Why don't you split the list of emails with semi-colon delimited and  the validation on each element of the list? That way you allow only one `@`.

Comment: fine idea, will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard way to check emails with regex: `\b\w+@[\w.]+\.[A-z.]{2,4}\b`
It's not perfect, but it should work for your example.
You could also split the string by semicolons, and then validate the emails one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Validating emails one at the time is probably your most clean bet, otherwise the regex can get pretty ugly. Especially if you later add more complex requirements to the addresses. A big benefit of doing a single address at the time is that you have a well tried problem, namely [how to validate an email address using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?:(?:^|;)\w+(?:[-+.]\w+)*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)+$
```